# Flutter android app failed to get resource

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, openstreetmap

I am trying to build an app using open street map, and after adding **[flutter_osm_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_osm_plugin)** it hangs on "**Running Grade task 'assembleDebug'**".

Using **flutter run -v** I got this:

```
Failed to get resource: GET. [HTTP HTTP/1.1 521 : https://jitpack.io/com/github/MKergall/osmbonuspack/6.9.0/osmbonuspack-6.9.0.pom)]
```

Is there an alternate way to download the resource and what would it be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jitpack servers are down, you can get more updates here: https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io/issues/5337

Comment: When your comment gets approved half a year later, regarding an issue that only lasted a few days 